# Fetching employee signatures using Oauth2 without asking the user

Tags: ruby, google-email-settings-api

I administer a Google Apps account. We need to retrieve the email signatures for the employees in our domain in order to display them in an application we're working on. We need to do this programmatically on our servers, without any interaction from our employees.

Our codebase is in Ruby. I've gotten everything working by using ClientLogin ("google.com/accounts/ClientLogin") with our Google Apps administrator email address and password and then parsing out the token from that response and using it to make a call to "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/#{domain}/#{username}/signature".

However, we would like to do this the modern, non-deprecated way, which from what I read means using OAuth2. The problem I'm having is that I can't find a guide which clearly states how to do this. I've read the Python examples and code, but they all have a manual step where you enter a URL in your browser and click a button. Also, as we aren't using Python, it's not entirely straight forward to port these examples over in the first place because they all assume you're using other Python libraries.

Is there a clear explanation somewhere of how to obtain an authentication token for a google apps administrator using the new authentication mechanism and then using that token to submit a request to "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/#{domain}/#{username}/signature" to retrieve a user's signature?

It would be most helpful if the explanation were language agnostic (using straight HTTP calls), but if I absolutely port all of the code from another language then I will do that.

Comment: In Advanced Settings in admin.google.com, you can get an admin-level OAuth token which ought to have access to everything.

Comment: When I go to the page with header "Manage OAuth key and secret for this domain" there is a section that says "The key and secret above are able to access any user's data for all Google Data APIs. Learn more". When I click "Learn more" it takes me to a page about Oauth 1.0 and says that it's deprecated. Can you point me to an article about how to use the OAuth consumer key and OAuth consumer secret to access the emailsettings api using OAuth 2.0?

Comment: I suppose I should also note that I've gotten a token with the following: https://gist.github.com/MichaelBaker/d1ea2ccfde3417359a5c But when I submit that token with the email settings request under the `access_token` query param, the response is a 401.

Comment: Also, the client gem only seems to accept the consumer secret and key for the OAuth 1 client, not the OAuth 2 client: https://code.google.com/p/oauth-signet/wiki/SignetOAuth1Client

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

The Email Settings API will soon be deprecated hence I strongly suggest you to move to GMAIL API. There is a method that can help you retrieve the user signature and you can check the reference here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/get

In regards to getting the user's signature without any interaction from your employees, you will need to use a service account to impersonate the user and get the information. You can refer to this document for information on how to proceed https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts.

Hope this helps!